# Propagate new version of file(jar/.py) to airflow

Tags: python, scala, airflow, versioning

I am new person in Airflow but I do not know how to properly way publish new python scripts or jars to airflow server. The problematic part is **/home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/file1.py**. If I create a new version of **file1.py** I would like to propagate this new version on airflow server. The simple solution could be via FTP

I found [SFTPOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/ssh.html), which could be my first step in the application and get the desired version of my script. 

1) Is there a better approach than separate step in Aiflow? 
2) The second part of the question is to how handle the jar files. My solution is to publish jar file somewhere(for instance Nexus repository) and have the separate step in airflow which download latest version of my file.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator,PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                  datetime.min.time())

default_args = { ... }

//
f1 = SFTPOperator(...)

dag = DAG('simple', default_args=default_args)
t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='testairflow',
bash_command='python /home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/file1.py',
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking at is source code version control. You should treat your DAGs as any other code and version them in a Version Control System e.g. git. You can then use any continuous integration tool, or cron job to keep the DAGS in sync.

Airflow Refreshes the DAGS regularly (default : 30 Sec).